# reactgridlayout - unable to shrink columns

Tags: react-grid-layout

I am trying to shrink my webpage using react responsivegridlayout

Below is my code

```
  <ResponsiveGridLayout
  compactType="horizontal"
  layouts={{ lg: gridLayout }}
  breakpoints={{
    xl: 1920, lg: 1200, md: 996, sm: 768, xs: 576, xxs: 0,
  }}
  cols={{
    xl: 12, lg: 12, md: 12, sm: 9, xs: 6, xxs: 3,
  }}
  rowHeight={25}
  containerPadding={[0, 10]}
>
```

Horizontal compact is working, but vertical compact is not showing 2nd column when I try to shrink the webpage vertically. What could be the issue.